# Avoid whole html table shifting on next page in pdf format

Tags: pdf, html-table

When a table has more than one row it's automatically shifted onto the next page. I want to break that table so I can see half of the table rows on one page and remaining rows on next page.

Here's a screenshot

[image]

Comment: Its unclear what software you are asking about. Please show us some code that you want help with.

Comment: If you're using [iText 7 + pdfHTML](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml/chapter-1-hello-html-pdf), then we can't reproduce the problem. Please provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that people can run on their own machine so that they can check what goes wrong.